# Comment exprimer le « unhoard » de performances vidéoludiques ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, jargon

Le contexte est celui de la [performance vidéoludique](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26541710) ([*speedrun*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speedrun)) où l'on peut trouver un emploi de jargon d'usage très limité en langue anglaise: le ***unhoard*** et en contexte ça ressemble à la substantivation de la définition du verbe sur [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unhoard) en ligne (« to bring ( treasure etc) out of a hoard ») mais adaptée au contexte.

En fait, dans ce milieu, on publie constamment des vidéos de ses performances afin d'en établir la preuve. Le *unhoard* consiste à publier à un moment particulier et de manière très publique (dans cet univers-là, sur un site très connu de partage de vidéos) un montage de performances de jeu secrètes jusque là pour montrer des progrès récents ou un temps record établi en privé et pour épater la galerie.

Quel substantif, ou quel verbe exprimerait ce *un[hoard](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hoard#etymonline_v_12052)(ing)* de vidéos de performance de jeu ?

> Massive GoldenEye 007 & Perfect Dark World Record **Unhoard**!
>   [ Nom d'utilisateur ] **unhoard**.

Comment: En gros il s'agit d'une preuve vidéo de quelquechose, ou alors le unhoard est le moment où l'on publie cette preuve ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Ça implique qu'on ne publie pas pendant un moment, qu'on garde ses performances secrètes et qu'on décide de publier ce qu'on a amassé à un moment ; la publication suite à ça, c'est ça le _unhoard_. ... Ce n'est pas employé pour signifier _preuve_ mais ça peut en constituer une.

Comment: Le but est de _terminer un jeu vidéo le plus rapidement possible_ (par ex. le [record du monde](https://youtu.be/1wR8x5b_ExM) de Super Mario any% = 4:55.646 ; il y a des catégories, « n'importe quel % » complété, avec ou sans _glitch_, voire ACE, ou 100% complété). Il faut prouver donc les joueurs publient régulièrement. Avec certaines techniques, comme l’exécution de [code arbitraire](https://youtu.be/OAytRB3mvMo) ou certains raffinements, ça peut demander de la recherche, de la pratique etc. Certains se regroupent et veulent créer un impact lors de la publication, que ce soit le temps...

Comment: record, la technique etc. Quand je parle de montage je ne parle pas de tricher en assemblant des vidéos de meilleurs segments en prétendant qu'il s'agit d'une partie linéaire, je parle d'un montage d'avancées, ou montrant une ou des progression de temps record etc. qu'on choisit de publier à un moment particulier. Les [techniques](https://youtu.be/fxZuzos7Auk) employées aujourd'hui intéressent certainement les développeurs et il y a un débat sur ce qui constitue _jouer_ dans ce contexte etc.

Answer (score 1):

Si j'ai bien compris la question et son contexter ainsi que les commentaires, je pense que le terme "unhoard" encapsule 2 choses:

1. Le fait de rendre quelquechose public. On pourra utiliser des termes comme "publier","mettre à disposition","livrer","poster"
2. Le fait que ce "quelquechose" est un montage, un ensemble, une compilation d'autres choses plus petites dont le nom en anglais ou en français n'est pas spécifié.On pourra utiliser des termes comme "compilation","montage","paquet","groupe","moments choisis"

Il faudra ensuite composer une expression avec ces termes car à ma connaissance il n'existe pas de traduction littérale du verbe "unhoard" en français (google translate me donne "se défaire" mais ca ne semble pas correspondre à la signification utilisée ici).

Comment: Ta réponse est méthodique mais seulement à la fin voit-on poindre ce qui m'intéresse vraiment. Le deuxième élément est une technicalité. Je te rappelle qu'il s'agit de jargon, dans cet univers-là des termes rappellant la piraterie (trésor etc.) abondent. Dans 1. tu proposes _livrer_, je vais te dire _évènement de livraison de marchandise_ qui n'est pas utile mais m'aide à t'expliquer davantage ce que je recherche. Je t'invite à t'approprier le verbe mais à te détacher de sa traduction, disons que ce qui mène à l'action c'est _amasser du butin_, quel réflexe ça déclenchje pour l'action d'après?

Comment: Aussi note que le verbe est préfixé avec un-, l'action contraire de _hoard_ dans notre cas, bien ça peut fournir une piste de solution disons un verbe ou un nom qui est préfixé de la même manière ? Le contexte de la « vente » est peut-être utile ; j'ai pensé à _A Christmas Carol_ (Scrooge), dans le segment où il est mort deux domestiques ont pris la literie ou les rideaux et vont chez un brocanteur, chacune met ce qu'elle a sur la table et le brocanteur fixe le prix. Ce que ces choses évoquent est peut être utile. Je m'intéresse davantage à comment ces références se transposent (le réflexe)...